# I need way to find all files containing odd ^M invisible characters

Tags: php, bash, replace, line-endings, newline

I know for a fact that these PHP files exist. I can open them in VIM and see the offending character.

I found several links here on stackoverflow that suggest remedies for this but none of them work properly. I know for a fact that several files do not contain the ^M characters (CRLF line endings) however, I keep getting false positives.

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec fgrep -l $'\r' "{}" \;
```

Returns false positives.

```
find . -not -type d -name "*.php" -exec file "{}" ";" | grep CRLF
```

Returns nothing.

etc...etc...

Edit: Yes, I am executing these lines in the offending directory.

Comment: Is your goal to convert the `\r\n` to `\n`? If so would it not be easier to simply do `dos2unix *.php`?

Comment: Both work for me.  I'd suggest some debugging steps: take one of the files the first is giving false positives on, and try `fgrep $'\r' /path/to/file.php | cat -v | more` and see what it thinks it's finding.  For the second, try without the `grep` and see what file's outputting for the files with CRLFs.

Comment: Do you have `dos2unix` installed? That's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a source control repository for storing your files? Many of them have the ability to automatically make sure that line endings of files are correct upon commit. I can give you an example with Subversion.

I have a [pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) that allows me to specify what properties in Subversion must be on what files in order for those files to be committed. For example, I could specify that any file that ends in `*.php` must have the property `svn:eol-style` set to `LF`.

If you use this, you'll never have an issue with the `^M` line endings again.

As for finding them, I've been able to do this:

```
$ find . -type f -exec egrep -l "^M$" {} \;
```

Where `^M` is a Control-M. With Bash or Kornshell, you can get that by pressing Control-V, then Control-M. You might have to have `set -o vi` for it to work.

Comment: I like your comment about the pre-commit hook!

Answer (score 1):

A little Perl can not only reveal the files but change them as desired.  To find your culprits, do:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec perl -ne 'print $ARGV if m{\r$}' {} + > badstuff
```

Now, if you want to remove the pesky carriage return:

```
perl -pe 's{\r$}{}' $(<badstuff)
```

...which eliminates the carriage return from all of the affected files.  If you want to do that and create a backup copy too, do:

```
perl -pi.old -e 's{\r$}{}' $(<badstuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command will tell you which kinds of line-end characters it sees:

```
$ file to-do.txt
to-do.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ file mixed.txt
mixed.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

So you could run e.g.

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec file "{}" \; | grep -c CRLF
```

to count the number of files that have at least some CRLF line endings.

You could also use `dos2unix` or `fromdos` to convert them all to LF only:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec dos2unix "{}" \;
```

You might also care if these tools would touch all of the files, or just the ones that have to be converted; check the tool documentation

Comment: @all, Yes, it would be useful to convert them however, only in the future, after I definitely identify that they need conversion. Additionally, I want to write a report listing all the files for other developers to review before doing a drastic conversion on thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the instructions provided at http://kb.iu.edu/data/agiz.html to do this. The following will change the ^M in a specific file to a \n return and place that into a new file using tr:

```
 tr '\r' '\n' < macfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

This does the same thing just using perl instead. With this one you can probably pipe in a series of files:

```
  perl -p -e 's/\r/\n/g'  < macfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```